# What are the exact conditions, in terms of graph structure, where KVL can be applied?

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

This might be a really dumb question, but ...

My understanding of KVL (Kirchoff Voltage Law) is that when you sum
all voltages around a circuit "loop", then the sum is zero.

Fair enough, but in every textbook I've read so far, I have yet to find
a clean, an more importantly formal definition of what a "loop" is.

Is a "loop" any cycle in the circuit graph ?

For example, in the circuit below, can I apply KVL to the left loop, in spite
of it having a short to ground in the middle ?

Is it correct to write `v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 = 0` even when v3 is shorted to
ground ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEC0Fe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: v3 is not shorted to ground, it is *defined* as ground and therefore 0V. A circuit needs a ground reference (0V) to be able to analyze it with KVL.

Comment: @jippie : sure, but not certain how relevant that is to the question ... if you just imagine V3 connected to a DC source, the question still stands.

Comment: @jippie, it is *not* the case that a circuit needs a ground reference to apply KVL; node voltage analysis requires a 0V reference.  See my answer.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri you are right, I shouldn't comment here when watching TV ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misconception here that needs to be cleared up quickly.

When one does KVL 'round a loop one is summing the voltages *across* the circuit elements in the loop.

[image]

However, you've marked *node voltages* on your schematic which are, by definition, the voltage from that node to the ground (datum, common, zero reference...) node.

To make it clear, the voltage you've denoted V1 is the *sum* of the voltages across R1 and R3.  This is a *consequence* of KVL.

So *no*, you cannot meaningfully sum the node voltages and set them to zero.  That would be a misapplication of KVL.

---

Here are some examples to consider:

By KVL, the voltage across R1 is (V1 - V2).

By KVL, the voltage across R2 is V2 (V3 = 0).

By KVL, the voltage V1 is the sum of the above voltages:  V1 = (V1 - V2) + V2

---

Here's yet another way to look at it.

The voltage V1 is *measured* by placing the red lead of the voltmeter at node 1 and the black lead at the ground node.

The voltage across R1 is *measured* by placing the red lead at node 1 and the black lead at node 2.

The voltage across R2 is *measured* by placing the red lead at node 2 and the black lead at node 3 (the ground node).

By, KVL, the measured voltage across R1 plus the measured voltage across R2 must equal the measured voltage across V1.

Comment: thanks, this is very useful (thanks to it, found the error I had in my calculations). However, it still doesn't entirely address my question ... in the schematic you drew, if a branch goes from after - say - R3 to another part of the circuit, can I still apply KVL. In other words : what is the exact definition of a "loop" in terms of graphs.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute voltage at any point on the loop, with respect to ground, is irrelevant. The fact that one of the nodes in the loop is defined to be ground is irrelevant. You could have a voltage source that raises the voltage at v3 to 100V above ground and it would not matter. KVL still applies.

However, you may have a misunderstanding about the meaning of KVL. The voltage law doesn't say that the sum of the *voltages* around any closed loop is zero, it says that the sum of the voltage *increases* around any loop must be zero. Equivalently, the sum of the voltage *decreases* around any loop must be zero. So, starting at your ground node and proceeding clockwise:

\$(v4 - v3) + (v1 - v4) + (v2 - v1) + (v3 - v2) = 0\$

Algebraically, this tells you that \$0 = 0\$, which is not much help, so you need other information to actually solve for the node voltages.